# JavaScript/jQuery: event fired twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, google-chrome

I'm trying some event bindings with jQuery, and I have this simple code in my document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p a").each(function(i, selected){
        $(selected).hover(
            function(event) { alert('over: ' + event.type); },
            function(event) { alert('out: ' + event.type); });
        }
    )
});
```

So, when I move mouse over a link thats inside a paragraph (selector is "p a") alerts pop-up twice. So, mouseenter and mouseleave are fired twice.

This only happens in Google Chrome. In Internet Explorer 7, [Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox) 3, [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) and [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) both events are fired only once.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think somehow the alert is actually causing the extra events in Chrome. With the following code I only see one event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p a").each(function(i, selected){
    $(selected).hover( 
      function(event) { $("p").append('<br>over: ' + event.type); }, 
      function(event) { $("p").append(' out: ' + event.type); });
    }
  )
});
```

Comment: Yup - as soon as the alert is shown, another mouseover event is triggered.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I've checked Safari - there the alert "kills" the mouseleave event...

Answer (score 8):

I suppose this doesn't answer your question, but this post came up while researching my own bug. It turned out the problem was that I had inadvertently included an external javascript twice.

Just thought it would be worthwhile to document this for others who have the same problem. An obvious error that took a while to track down!