# jQuery hover event firing twice on mouse over

Tags: jquery, hover

I'm trying to temporarily change the contents of a `div` on hover, using this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var $ratingHtml = '';
    $('.userRating').hover(
        function() {
            $ratingHtml = $(this).html();
            alert($ratingHtml);
            $(this).html( 'Log in to rate' );
        },
        function() {
            alert($ratingHtml);
            $(this).html( $ratingHtml );            
        }
    );
});
```

However on hover, the alert appears twice - first for the original HTML content, then again for the string 'Log in to rate'. It seems like a second mouseover event occurs. How can I work around this?

Comment: Does it still do it if you remove the alerts? You could be getting a new event when you dismiss the alert since the element may lose focus when the alert pops up.

Comment: @tvanfosson: No, the alerts were only added for debugging purposes, the same thing happens without them.

Comment: Have you tried changing the text then instead of the html?  I see that adding a DIV works, but I wonder if just using `.text()` would work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to go with a different solution - adding the text in an overlay:

```
$('.userRating').hover(
    function() {
        $('<div class="loginMsg">Log in to rate</div>').appendTo('.userRating');
    },
    function() {
        $('.loginMsg').remove();
    }
);
```

With appropriate styles in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because of event propagation. See these links on how to avoid it:

[How to stop event propagation with inline onclick attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute)

http://snipplr.com/view/2810/stop-event-propagation-stop-an-event-from-bubbling-up/

Comment: Hmm... is there no "jQuery" way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

this question was already asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598276/javascript-jquery-event-fired-twice) @ stackoverflow.com....

you could make use of this jQuery [plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)... It will help you with the hover...