# my hover function in jquery it's not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to append p tag with some text and i trying to show alert message when hover that p tag content but here it's not working here is my code:[code](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/37TUN/)

Comment: If you're going to add multiple elements (as is possible in your demo), use `class` instead of `id`. `id` is meant to be unique throughout the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/37TUN/3/ Instead of `click` and `hover`, I used the `live` function.

Here's the code:

```
$('#addmore').live("click", function(){
   $('<p id="text3">text3</p>').appendTo('#paragraph_div');
});   
$('#text3').live("mouseover", function(){
   alert('its done!');
});
```

Comment: This is acceptable, but take note that there are some [serious drawbacks](http://api.jquery.com/live/) with `live` and that it has been deprecated. If possible I would bind the event after the fact as needed, and when not possible use `delegate` or `on`.

Comment: @DavidBrainer-Banker Thanks for the heads-up! I'll take at look at the other things, this was just the best way that I knew how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to [move your code around a little bit](http://jsfiddle.net/37TUN/1/). Here is what I changed:

```
$('#addmore').click(function() {
    $('#paragraph_div').append("<p id='text3'>text3</p>");
    $('#text3').hover(function() {
        alert('its done!');
    });
});
```

You were trying to bind the `hover` event before you had created the div to bind it to. I moved it inside the `click` event where you were actually creating the `text3` div. You need to remember to always bind events *after* creating new dom elements.

Note that as mentioned in some other answers you can use `live` (deprecated), `delegate` or `on` (1.7+). However, I tend to err on the side of adding events to elements after creation whenever it is reasonable to do so.

Also, calling an alert during a `hover` event may not really make sense depending on your intent. You might want to use the `hover` to display a div or perform another action. If you want to popup the alert it would be better to use `mouseover`. See [JavaScript/jQuery: event fired twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598276/javascript-jquery-event-fired-twice) for more details.

```
$('#addmore').click(function() {
    $('#paragraph_div').append("<p id='text3'>text3</p>");
    $('#text3').mouseover(function() {
        alert('its done!');
    });
});
```

Comment: That calls the alert twice, however.

Comment: @Prisoner Do you mean if you add more than one element with an ID of `text3`? You definitely should not be adding multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: No, its doing it if I only create one #text3 and hover over it (alert box twice) - using Chrome 15.

Comment: @Prisoner The issue you are referring to is related to the interaction between alert and hover (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598276/javascript-jquery-event-fired-twice). It would be better to use mouseover or something other than an alert. I was simply responding the original poster's question.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `hover()` on an element that's not yet in the DOM. To work around this, use `on()`:

```
  $('#paragraph_div').on('mouseover','#text3',function(e){
        if ($(e.target).is('#text3')){
            alert("It's done!");
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/37TUN/4/).

As noted in the comments, by Alnitak, `on()` is only available with jQuery version 1.7 and above. To use a version of jQuery prior to version 1.7, you can use `delegate()` to much the same effect:

```
  $('#paragraph_div').delegate('#text3','mouseover',function(e){
        if ($(e.target).is('#text3')){
            alert("It's done!");
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/37TUN/9/) using jQuery 1.4.4 (just to demonstrate a different version).

Comment: but only if you're using jQuery 1.7+, otherwise use `.live()`

Comment: Well, prior to 1.7 `delegate()` is the preferred option (according to the notes for [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)).

Answer (score 0):

1st thing please remove  `document` quotes.
2nt thing is change the `hover` to live with events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` because `hover` implicitly invoke events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.
check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/37TUN/10/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#addmore').click(function(){
$('#paragraph_div').append("<p id='text3'>text3</p>");
});
$('#text3').live('mouseenter mouseleave',function(){
alert('its done!');
});
});
```