# flippy jquery effect doesn't rotate correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flip

I have a problem with flip effect on jquery plugin.When the image rotates it does not rotate correctly.I dont know why but i spent hours and no solution please help.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="Flip-jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="Flip-jQuery/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="Flip-jQuery/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
<script src="Flip-jQuery/jquery.flip.js"></script>


<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#box1").on('mouseover',function(){
        $(".flip").flip({
            direction:'lr',
            content:'hello',
            color:'red'
            });
    })
    $('.revert').on('click',function(){
        $('.flip').revertFlip();
        })
});
</script>


#main{                      
    border:1px solid red;
    width:500px;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
}
#box1, #box2{
    border:2px solid black;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
</style>
<div id='main'>

<div id='box1' class='flip'>
box1
</div>

<div id='box2'>
box2
</div>

<a style=" float:right;" href="#" class="revert">Click to revert</a>

</div>
```

Here is the whole code.I have tried anything but nothing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the flip api, it looks like the direction attribute is called before the others, try that. Also, the initial function seems irrelevant. Try wrapping it in the `$(document.ready()` function

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#box1").on('mouseover',function(){
        $(".side2").flip({
            direction:'lr', //in the flip API direction seems to come first in every example
            content:'hello',
            color:'red'
        });
    })
});
```

You also have a syntax error in your HTML:

```
<div id='main'> 

    <div id='box1' class='side1'"> <!-- HERE remove that double quote -->
    box1
    </div>

    <div id='box2' class='side2'>
    box2
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate for the response.Nothing happens, the rotation begin right but at the middle it disappears.(it does not rotate 360deg/180deg).

Answer (score 0):

You have included the flip.js plugin twice in your HTML header.

Answer (score 0):

Check this thing i get what the problem was. Basically you are triggering twice the mouse over event [JavaScript/jQuery: event fired twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598276/javascript-jquery-event-fired-twice)